# Constructing macrovariable name in SELECT..INTO-clause using %SCAN()

Tags: macros, sas

I'm trying to create `macrovariable`, using as its name concatenation of two strings, one of them - result of `%SCAN()` function. All it happens inside a macro. But `macrovariable` is not created and log says that reference to this `macrovariable` is not resolved, though generated open code looks ok.

Here's an example:

```
%macro test;
proc sql;
    select max(height) into :height%scan(999 3,1)
    from sashelp.class;
quit;
%mend test;
%test

%put &height999;
```

Log:

```
MACROGEN(TEST):   proc sql;
MACROGEN(TEST):   select max(height) into :height999 from sashelp.class;
MACROGEN(TEST):   quit;
NOTE: PROCEDURE SQL used (Total process time):
    real time           0.05 seconds
    cpu time            0.01 seconds



         %put &height999;
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference HEIGHT999 not resolved.
&height999
```

But if I do the same in open code everything works fine:

```
proc sql;
    select max(height) into :height%scan(999 3,1)
    from sashelp.class;
quit;
%put &height999;
```

Log:

```
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable HEIGHT999 resolves to       72
```

I suspect that I still don't understand something about macro mechanics in SAS. Or is it specific of SELECT INTO?

Comment: Useful SAS Macro Language reference: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#titlepage.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that's because that macro variable created inside `%test` is local to `%test` so you can't call it outside.

You could specify it to be a global variable using `%global hight999;`

Comment: Yep.  SQL actually might create it in the global table if you just create a global variable with %let in open code - this would cause it to have variable functionality.

Comment: Thanks, you saved me from asylum :)